# QProgressBar does not display text

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to display percentages next to a progress bar, see code below:

```
m_bar = new QProgressBar(this);
m_bar->setFormat("%p%");
m_bar->setTextVisible(true);
```

The progress bar is displayed but the percentages aren't. It is to be noted that I'm on MacOSx.

I searched about this issue and found (here: https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/71704-Show-text-(percentage-completed)-of-QProgressBar-on-Mac-using-macintosh-style) : "The macintosh style on the Mac still does not show the percentage completed on a QProgressBar. A workaround is to put a label above/beside/bottom of the progress bar and manually (through code) put in completion percentages into the label."

Could anyone confirm that the above statement is true? Or is my code wrong?

Comment: It's from 2021 so I don't see why it should not be true anymore. Your code is fine and you can check it when you use e.g. the 'windows' style.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to Qt (and programming) and was just not sure. The QProgressBar documentation states "This property (setTextVisible()) may be ignored by the style (e.g., QMacStyle never draws the text). Does it translate to "You can't display text on macOS"?

Comment: Just tried your code and can confirm that no text is shown regardless of the format specifier I tried.  The text *is* visible, however, if I force the style to `Windows` or `Fusion` using either `QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=Fusion path-to-exe` or `path-to-exe -style Fusion` .  Probably not what you wanted to hear, but... :-(

Comment: Thanks G.M - I actually found a way to set the style of a widget (and not the whole app) using this `m_bar->setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("Fusion"));`